# Starlike sets in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, convexity, several-complex-variables

Let $S$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$. $S$ is called starlike about the point $x_0\in S$ if for every point of $S$, the segment of the straight line from the point to $x_0$ lies in $S$. If $S$ is starlike about the origin, then it is easy to see that $\overline{S}$ is also starlike about the origin.
I wanted to know if there are any necessary and sufficient conditions for which the set of points with respect to which $S$ is starlike, has a non-empty interior?

Also let $S$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}^2 $ which is starlike about the origin. Let $S_\mathbb{R}$ denote the restriction of $S$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. If I know that the set of points about which $S_\mathbb{R}$ is starlike is a singleton set. Then can I deduce anything about $S$? Will it also be starlike about only a singleton?

Comment: I think it would help to know what is the answer for polygons in the real plane. It looks like a necessary condition for the set of "starlike points" to have a nonempty interior would be that every two interior points can be connected by a broken line segment consisting of two pieces and never touching the boundary. Is this sufficient?

Comment: @Derek But we do not even know if there is more than one starlike point.

Comment: If the condition I stated is equivalent to "there is an interior point P which can see all interior points" then a neighbourhood of P would probably consist of starlike points by an appropriate continuity argument. But I do not know (a) if the two conditions are equivalent or (b) if the continuity argument can fail in some weird case...